# How can I remove css like sequences in plain text strings in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I get plain text strings from a software (no html) which contains css sequences like this:

```
Some plain text... 

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

    .afooter {
        color: #fff !important;
    }

Some other plain text...
```

How can I remove these sequences? To me it looks like css, however, it is not surrounded by css script tag. The result I'm expecting is:

```
Some plain text... 


Some other plain text...
```

I tried to create a html like string by adding `<html><body>MY PLAIN TEXT</body></html>` and checked if I can remove it using the HtmlAgilityPack. However, the sequences are not parsed as css node since they are part of the plain text (not surrounded by any tags) for some reason.

Comment: Have you even tried *anything*? We´re not here to do your work.

Comment: and when you try anything, don't [try regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1132334).

Comment: I tried to create a html like string by adding <html><body>MY PLAIN TEXT </body></html> and checked if i can remove it using the HtmlAgilityPack. However, the sequences are not parsed as css node.

Comment: [`[^{\n]*{\s*[^}]*}`](https://regex101.com/r/LQ6IAs/2) Does this work?

Comment: @dlatikay Any reason why I should not use a regex? Can you recommend any frameworks/libraries I could use to solve it?

Comment: The solution depends on other content of your plain text. The solution depends on other content of your plain text. Are there `{` or `}` symbols in your plain text excluding region of interest?

Comment: @Michael just joking. that approach with the agility pack could be promising. it may never be 100% exact. what if you fed it the <style> tags as well? basically saying, parse the whole body as css and all that wouldn't parse is the plain text you want as output?

Comment: Not sure how I could fed the <style> tag without detecting the area where I need to add <style> and </style> tags. I'm receiving the plain text from some other blackbox software, so I'm not able to change it :-/

Comment: Instead of extracting those parts of your inout that are invalid, why not concentrate on the *actual* content? Try to parse everything line by line and remove everything that doesn´t fit your expected style. Is there any common format on which you can rely for the other text?

Comment: wrap everything in <html><head><style>raw-content</style></head><body></body>, then have a sufficiently tolerant parser try to interpret that as CSS and everything it can't, is your plain text residue.

Comment: @dlatikay i can try this by tomorrow

Comment: @Gurman your regex seems to work for now, I will need to test it with some more data, so I will get back to you to give you feedback. Thank you!
Maybe you can post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I've updated my question since you've probably downvoted it right away. To answer your question: I have no common format I can rely on, the texts are extracted from email live data by the blackbox software I'm using.

Comment: @Michael Sure. Let me know if you come across the case where it doesn't work.